# How to push a value into an existing array of mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table of column name "access" which has array values [2,3,4]
Now I want to push a single value in the last part of the array. if my value is '7' so after pushing the array should be [2,3,4,7]

Here's the access column.

[image: This is my access column]

I used this but i know it won't happen because it removes all the existing values

```
$id = '7'
UPDATE user SET access = '$id' WHERE name = '$user'
```

Comment: Did you try using concat()？

Comment: Is that a JSON or a TEXT column?

Comment: @brombeer TEXT column

Comment: So, those aren't array values but simple text. Use `concat()` as Ken Lee suggested or normalize your data, one row per access level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting comma-separated values into a SQL column is a misuse of SQL, and that's why you can't find any clean way to do this.

If you *must* do things this way, try this.

```sql
UPDATE user SET access = CASE 
         WHEN access IS NULL OR access = '' THEN $id
         WHEN FIND_IN_SET($id,access) IS NOT NULL THEN access
         ELSE CONCAT_WS(',',access,$id) END
 WHERE whatever;
```

The first WHEN handles the situation where `access` doesn't contain anything. The second handles the case where your `$id` value is already in `access`. And the ELSE appends your `$id` value.

But if you can, do this the SQL way instead. Try creating a separate table called `user_access`. Give it a `user` and an `access` column. Then INSERT a row to the table to add an `$id`, and DELETE one to remove. Why? You have a many::one relationship between access $id values and users, and that's done with a table.

Comment: It didn't work. when access is empty it is putting value but when there is a value already it did nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your second suggestion. but I have almost 1000+ access id for a single user. so if I create a separate table than there will be 1000+ rows for every user. is it a good idea? I have very little knowledge about it.

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea. SQL databases are *far* better at handling your use case with a separate table than they are at handling very long strings of comma-separated numbers.